# Firebase + Turbo repo - Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully

Tags: node.js, firebase, turborepo

I have a basic firebase project called `api` inside the `apps/` directory in my turbo-repo.
I also have a `project-constants` package in the `packages/` directory.

When installing and importing the `project-constants` package in my `api/src/index.ts` i get errors! see below...

### apps/api

##### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "dev": "npm run build:watch | firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1",
    "openai": "3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.9.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0",
    "types": "*",
    "project-constants": "*"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

##### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

##### index.ts

```js
/**
 * Import function triggers from their respective submodules:
 *
 * import {onCall} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
 * import {onDocumentWritten} from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";
 *
 * See a full list of supported triggers at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions
 */

import { onRequest } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import * as logger from "firebase-functions/logger";
import constants from "project-constants";

// Start writing functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript

export const helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
  logger.info("Hello logs!", { constants }, { structuredData: true });
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

### packages/project-constants

##### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "project-constants",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "latest"
  }
}
```

##### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "preserveWatchOutput": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

##### index.ts

```js
const constants = {
  NODE_ENV: "process.env.NODE_ENV",
  POCKET_NHS_API_PORT: "process.env.API_PORT",
  API_URL: "process.env.API_URL",
  OPEN_API_KEY: "process.env.OPEN_API_KEY",
  FIREBASE_API_KEY: "process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY",
  FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN:
    "process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN",
  FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: "process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID",
  FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET:
    "process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET",
  FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID:
    "process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
  FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID:
    "process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID",
  FIREBASE_APP_ID_ANDROID:
    "process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID_ANDROID",
  FIREBASE_APP_ID_IOS: "process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID_IOS",
  FIREBASE_APP_ID_WEB: "process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID_WEB",
  LOGSNAG_API_KEY: "process.env.LOGSNAG_API_KEY",
} as const;

export default constants
```

When i run `yarn workspace api dev` i get the following output:

```bash
$ yarn workspace api dev
yarn workspace v1.22.19
yarn run v1.22.19
$ npm run build:watch | firebase emulators:start --only functions
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: auth, firestore, database, hosting, pubsub, storage
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "/Users/name/Developer/app/apps/api" for Cloud Functions...
✔  functions: Using node@18 from host.
Serving at port 8807

shutdown requested via /__/quitquitquit

⬢  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://127.0.0.1:4000/               │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions │ 127.0.0.1:5001 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/functions │
└───────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500

Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the *-debug.log files.
```

### More info

##### Node version: 18

##### turbo.json

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://turbo.build/schema.json",
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "outputs": [".next/**", "!.next/cache/**", "dist/**"]
    },
    "build:web:ci": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "outputs": ["dist/**"]
    },
    "build:api": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "outputs": ["dist/**"]
    },
    "test": {
      "dependsOn": ["build"],
      "inputs": ["src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.ts", "test/**/*.ts", "test/**/*.tsx"]
    },
    "lint": {},
    "deploy": {
      "dependsOn": ["build", "test", "lint"]
    },
    "dev": {
      "cache": false,
      "persistent": true
    },
    "start": {
      "cache": false,
      "persistent": true
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be amazing, been hitting my head on the wall for a while on this

Github issue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6393